# Comment 'get_sidebar();' have no effect: remove sidebar from theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to remove the sidebars from a WordPress site;
should be a pretty straight-forward action to do, but I have a problem:
I've commented every get_sidebar() I've found in my theme PHP page (including index.php, page.php etc) but seem that have no effect on the site.

Here is an example from my `index.php`:

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="page-wrapper" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="page-content" class="col-sm-7 col-md-8">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'templates/page-title' ); ?>

                <?php $blog_layout = vw_get_option( 'blog_layout' ); ?>

                <?php if ( 'classic' == $blog_layout ) : ?>

                    <div class="row archive-posts post-box-list">
                        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 post-box-wrapper">
                                <?php get_template_part( 'templates/post-box/classic', get_post_format() ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div>

                <?php else: ?>

                <div class="row archive-posts vw-isotope post-box-list">
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 post-box-wrapper">
                            <?php get_template_part( 'templates/post-box/large-thumbnail', get_post_format() ); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'templates/pagination' ); ?>

                <?php comments_template(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts were found', 'envirra' ) ?></h2>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

        <!--aside id="page-sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper col-sm-5 col-md-4">
            <?php // get_sidebar(); ?>
        </aside-->
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

in the example above you can see both html / PHP comment, but I've also tried with only HTML comment / only PHP comment.

may notice that i'm using a Child theme, but I've found the get_sidebar() only in the father theme.

I'm probably missing something stupid, should i remove the entire line? i'm not an WordPress expert so i'd like to do the less intrusive modification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is an option within the most of WP themes to turn off the sidebar(s), also theme authors care to give you a simple checkbox for that in the single Page, Post, or even Category template, but sometimes there is no easy way out.

I suggest you check this [guide back from 2017](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-remove-the-sidebar-in-wordpress/) and a bit more fresh one [from 2019 here](https://dev.institute/blog/remove-hide-sidebar-wordpress-page/), most likely you will find your way without additional plugin in the first reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the first link is the one i've based my modification, with no success; i've tried the second one with the plugin and worked ok for the post/blog pages, but i've tried it on the homepage and it broke it :/ bad luck;

no option from the theme tho.

any other idea?

Comment: Well, in the worst case you can still hardcode it if you no longer plan to update the theme. Change class="col-sm-7 col-md-8" to class="col-md-12", seems like the sidebar shouldn't show up already but you still have some white space left after it.